# A vertical parabolic curve, $135$ meters long has a tangent grades of $-1.7 \space \%$ and $2.3 \%$. Find the sight distance in meters.

Tags: geometry

I am interested in answering this problem. It goes like this:

> A vertical parabolic curve, $135$ meters long has a tangent grades of $-1.7 \space \%$ and $2.3 \%$. Find the sight distance in meters.

**My work**

I don't know how to answer this.

I am interested in what topic in mathematics does the question belongs and I am curious in how to answer the problem above.

Thanks for helping me out:-)

Comment: Drawing a figure where you show what the given quantities refer to might help.

Comment: Here you have some material to begin with https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/surveying-and-transportation-engineering/parabolic-curve